# How make a table border thicker

Tags: tables

I need make the border of a table table thicker, as in the following image:

[image]

How can I do this?

My code is:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}

    \begin{document}
    \begingroup
    \def\arraystretch{2.2}%
    \begin{tabular}[]{|p{25mm}|c|c|c|}
      \hline
       \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{aaaaa} \\ % <===============================
      \hline
      \rowcolor{cyan}
      1 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
      \hline
      2 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
      \hline
      3 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
      \hline
      4 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
      \hline
      5 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \endgroup
    \end{document}
```

Comment: You may hate me for this comment, but I am really just trying to help. I would like to argue that you will be much better off if, instead of asking many questions, you'd ask less but clearer questions, and make even more effort to understand the answers.

Comment: Please google "latex beatiful tables". You will see that tables should have less lines - almost no lines. NOT thick lines.

Comment: By "[swelling] the border", are you referring to the *width*/*thickness* of the surrounding "frame"?

Comment: @Werner yes the edge that surrounds the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've well understood what you want, it's easy with `boldline`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{boldline} 

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\def\arraystretch{2.2}%
\begin{tabular}[]{V{4}p{25mm}|c|c|cV{4}}
  \hlineB{4}
   \multicolumn{4}{V{4}cV{4}}{aaaaa} \\ % <===============================
  \hline
  \rowcolor{cyan}
  1 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
  2 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
  3 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
  4 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
  5 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hlineB{3}
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One option is to insert the table into a tikz node with thick borders.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{2.2}%
    \node[draw,ultra thick,inner sep=.4pt]{\begin{tabular}[]{|p{25mm}|c|c|c|}
      \hline
       \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{aaaaa} \\ % <===============================
      \hline
      \rowcolor{cyan}
      1 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
      \hline
      2 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
      \hline
      3 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
      \hline
      4 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
      \hline
      5 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

You can place the entire `tabular` inside an `\fbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2.2}%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{2.6pt}%
\fbox{%
  \begin{tabular}{|p{25mm}|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{aaaaa} \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{cyan}
    1 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
    \hline
    2 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
    \hline
    3 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
    \hline
    4 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
    \hline
    5 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}%
}
\endgroup

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{ p{25mm} *{3}{c} }
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{4}{c}{aaaaa} \\
  \midrule
  \rowcolor{cyan}%
  1 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  2 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  3 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  4 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  5 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I'd be more inclined to use [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) to set the table:

[image]