# How to duplicate the content in just one table

Tags: tables

How to duplicate the content in just one  table and make it look like this:

[image]

I do not want two tables, I just want a table just one

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{boldline} 

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\def\arraystretch{2.2}%
\begin{tabular}[]{V{4}p{25mm}|c|c|cV{4}}
  \hlineB{4}
   \multicolumn{4}{V{4}cV{4}}{aaaaa} \\ % <===============================
  \hline
  \rowcolor{cyan}
  1 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
  2 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
  3 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
  4 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
  5 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hlineB{3}
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

**my intent is : 
How can I put the thickest side edges?**

```
 \documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{boldline} 

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\def\arraystretch{2.2}%
\begin{tabular}{|p{25mm}|c|c|c|p{25mm}|c|c|c|}
  \hlineB{3}
  \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{aaaaa} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{aaaaa} \\ \hline

  \hline
  \rowcolor{cyan}
  1 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
   1 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
     \hline
   1 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\


  \hlineB{4}
\end{tabular}
\endgroup


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should be more clear in your question. Currently it seems like a duplicate of [How make a table border thicker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/471512/5764), since you're only interested in a single table.

Comment: @Werner  I need that table too, the same table duplicate and triple it

Comment: @x-rw Your question is very unclear. Do you want to have the horizontal lines joined or separated? Do you want the border to be a bit broken in the middle? et cetera... Please make a clear sketch showing what you want to have.

Comment: @JouleV i edited my question, see please the figure

Comment: @Werner 
I would like an answer with the same code that I post, try try but not achieve please help me

Answer (score 3):

### Original answer

> Not solving the OP's problem

Do as usual:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{boldline} 

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\def\arraystretch{2.2}%
\begin{tabular}[]{V{4}p{25mm}|c|c|cV{4}}
  \hlineB{4}
   \multicolumn{4}{V{4}cV{4}}{aaaaa} \\ % <===============================
  \hline
  \rowcolor{cyan}
  1 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
  2 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
  3 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
  4 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
  5 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hlineB{3}
\end{tabular}
\endgroup
\begingroup
\def\arraystretch{2.2}%
\begin{tabular}[]{V{4}p{25mm}|c|c|cV{4}}
  \hlineB{4}
   \multicolumn{4}{V{4}cV{4}}{aaaaa} \\ % <===============================
  \hline
  \rowcolor{cyan}
  1 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
  2 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
  3 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
  4 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
  5 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hlineB{3}
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Edit 1

As the above is not Ok, I decided to go on a totally new way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.2}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,line width=2pt,inner sep=.4pt]{
    \begin{tabular}{|p{25mm}|c|c|c|c|p{25mm}|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{aaaaa} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{aaaaa} \\ \hline
        \rowcolor{cyan} 
        1   & a1  & a2  & a3  & a4 & 1   & a1  & a2  & a3  & a4  \\ \hline
        2   & a1  & a2  & a3  & a4 & 2   & a1  & a2  & a3  & a4  \\ \hline
        3   & a1  & a2  & a3  & a4 & 3   & a1  & a2  & a3  & a4  \\ \hline
        4   & a1  & a2  & a3  & a4 & 4   & a1  & a2  & a3  & a4  \\ \hline
        5   & a1  & a2  & a3  & a4 & 5   & a1  & a2  & a3  & a4  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Edit 2

Minor changes in formatting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

%% NECESSARY LINE
%% Add this line to your preamble
\usepackage{tikz}
%% End of Necessary line

% Note that the table is wider than the default margin in article class. You should change 
% the margin or make the table smaller.

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\begin{tikzpicture}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.2}
\node[draw,line width=2pt,inner sep=.4pt]{
    \begin{tabular}{|p{25mm}|c|c|c|c|p{25mm}|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{aaaaa} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{aaaaa} \\ \hline
        \rowcolor{cyan} 
        1   & a1  & a2  & a3  & a4 & 1   & a1  & a2  & a3  & a4  \\ \hline
        2   & a1  & a2  & a3  & a4 & 2   & a1  & a2  & a3  & a4  \\ \hline
        3   & a1  & a2  & a3  & a4 & 3   & a1  & a2  & a3  & a4  \\ \hline
        4   & a1  & a2  & a3  & a4 & 4   & a1  & a2  & a3  & a4  \\ \hline
        5   & a1  & a2  & a3  & a4 & 5   & a1  & a2  & a3  & a4  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but i want only one table

Comment: @x-rw: ...so you want two tables, but here you comment you only want one? Can you see how this is not clear?

Comment: @Werner 
I want to duplicate and triple the content but that is just a table

Comment: @x-rw: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

This solution puts tabulars inside a tabular.  Getting rid of the gaps at the edges was tricky.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{boldline} 

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\def\arraystretch{2.2}%
\sbox0{\begin{tabular}[]{@{\hspace{\tabcolsep}}p{25mm}|c|c|c@{\hspace{\tabcolsep}}}
   \multicolumn{4}{c}{aaaaa} \\ % <===============================
  \hline
  \rowcolor{cyan}
  1 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
  2 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
  3 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
  4 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
  5 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
\end{tabular}}%
\begin{tabular}{V{4}@{}l@{}|@{}l@{}V{4}}
  \hlineB{4}
  \usebox0 & \usebox0 \\
  \hlineB{3}
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{boldline} 

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\def\arraystretch{2.2}%
\begin{tabular}{V{4}p{25mm}|c|c|c|p{25mm}|c|c|cV{4}}
  \hlineB{3}
  \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{V{4}cV{1}}{aaaaa} & \multicolumn{4}{cV{4}}{aaaaa} \\ \hline

  \hline
  \rowcolor{cyan}
  1 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
   1 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
     \hline
   1 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\


  \hlineB{4}
\end{tabular}
\endgroup


\end{document}
```